# Prevent web pages from automatically reloading

Tags: google-chrome

I have a site that I follow frequently
The problem is that it refreshes the page every five minutes
And I never want this.
Here, an addition to the Firefox browser named "**stop auto reload**" When you put the name of this site, it prevents it from updating every five minutes.
But I prefer the Chrome browser
Can I find a way to prevent this update?
Now I use the method "press **F12**, then choose **console**, then type the following command:"

**window.onbeforeunload = function () {return 'Reload?';}**

To alert every five minutes to prevent it from updating, but it is a stressful and arduous method. Is there a better solution?
Please Help

Plugin: A plugin created on the Chrome browser

Comment: Please add "in Chrome browser" to your title.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon it's already in the tags